# Need pointers for optimization of Merge Sort implementation in Scala

Tags: scala, optimization, mergesort

I have just started learning Scala and sideways I am doing some algorithms also. Below is an implementation of merge sort in Scala. I know it isn't very "scala" in nature, and some might even reckon that I have tried to write java in scala. I am not totally familiar with scala, i just know some basic syntax and i keep googling if i need something more. So please give me some pointers on to what can i do in this code to make it more functional and in accord with scala conventions and best practices. Please dont just give correct/optimized code, i will like to do it myself. Any suggestions are welcomed !

```
def mergeSort(list: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    val len = list.length
    if (len == 1) list
    else {
      var x, y = new Array[Int](len / 2)
      val z = new Array[Int](len)
      Array.copy(list, 0, x, 0, len / 2)
      Array.copy(list, len / 2, y, 0, len / 2)
      x = mergeSort(x)
      y = mergeSort(y)
      var i, j = 0
      for (k <- 0 until len) {
        if (j >= y.length || (i < x.length && x(i) < y(j))) {
          z(k) = x(i)
          i = i + 1
        } else {
          z(k) = y(j)
          j = j + 1
        }
      }
      z
    }
  }
```

[EDIT] 
 This code works fine and I have assumed for now that input array will always be of even length.

**UPDATE**
Removed vars x and y

```
def mergeSort(list: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    val len = list.length
    if (len == 1) list
    else {
      val z = new Array[Int](len)
      val x = mergeSort(list.dropRight(len/2))
      val y = mergeSort(list.drop(len/2))
      var i, j = 0
      for (k <- 0 until len) {
        if (j >= y.length || (i < x.length && x(i) < y(j))) {
          z(k) = x(i)
          i = i + 1
        } else {
          z(k) = y(j)
          j = j + 1
        }
      }
      z
    }
  }
```

Comment: coursera ? :) if list is empty, will fail. if list has an odd size, x and y will have trouble

Comment: @twillouer yeah i am referring to coursera for algorithms study material. And for 2nd part list empty odd and all, i am working on that. For now i have assumed that list will always be of even length (mentioned that in question too !)

Comment: Do you want to optimize for performance, or do yuu just want it to be idiomatic scala? If you want learn how to write idiomatic scala, working with Arrays is not very helpful. But if you want maximum performance there is often no way around them.

Comment: i am not targeting performance here, its too early while i am still learning the language. I just want it to look more "scala" ,"functional"

Comment: I believe this question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `var x,y = ...` would be a good start to being functional. Prefer immutability to mutable datasets.

*HINT: a method swap that takes two values and returns them ordered using a predicate*

Also consider removing the `for` loop(or comprehension).

Comment: i did remove var x,y by introducing two new val x1, y1 after merge sort on each array, but my concern is : is the optimal ? increase no. of vals to remain functional ?

Comment: Its not a matter of increasing `val`s but reducing mutability. Functional style would also decompose the functions to smaller more specific(pure) units. This merge sort may be enhanced by adding a partial function to allow use of predicates when swapping. Also swapping can be a functional unit on its own.